# Pass argument to callback function COCOS2D Android

Tags: cocos2d-android, nosuchmethod

I've started working with cocos2d few days ago...and im working on small 2d game.
I figured out how to animate sprites. Now when sprite finished with animation I want it to be cleared from screen.

How to pass argument to callback function?

```
target.runAction(CCSequence.actions(repeatAnimation,
                        CCCallFuncND.action(this, "deleteTarget",target)));
```

Function is defined as:

```
public void deleteTarget(Object target)
```

It always gives me "NoSuchMethodException"...any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this

```
CCCallFuncN ccfun = CCCallFuncN.action(this, "test");

public void test(Object sender) {
    Do whatever you require
}
```